# assigning functions to std::function with same signature, but different calling convention fails

Tags: c++, mingw, std-function, stdcall, cdecl

the following compiles and runs just fine with mingw 4.7.2 and -m64 flag.

but with -m32 or with any mingw 32bit release it fails to compile. is it a bug or am i missing a compiler flag?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <functional>

    using namespace std;

    int __cdecl ccall(int i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int __stdcall stdcall(int i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int __fastcall fastcall(int i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    int main() {

        std::function<int(int)> fnc = ccall;
        fnc(10);

        std::function<int(int)> fnstd = stdcall;
        fnstd(100);

        std::function<int(int)> fnfast = fastcall;
        fnfast(200);

        return 0;
    }
```

error message:

```
    ...\Local\Temp\cc4ekW9J.s: Assembler messages:
    ...\Local\Temp\cc4ekW9J.s:30: Error: symbol `__ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFiiEPFiiEE9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_datai' is already defined 
    ...\Local\Temp\cc4ekW9J.s:80: Error: symbol `__ZNSt14_Function_base13_Base_managerIPFiiEE10_M_managerERSt9_Any_dataRKS4_St18_Manager_operation' is already defined
    ...\Local\Temp\cc4ekW9J.s:114: Error: symbol `__ZNSt14_Function_base13_Base_managerIPFiiEE10_M_managerERSt9_Any_dataRKS4_St18_Manager_operation' is already defined
```

i ended up doing it this way after "hiding" the call in a lambda function it works just fine:

```
    template<class Ret, class... Args> class StdCall
    {
    public:
        typedef Ret(__stdcall Fn_t)(Args...);
        typedef std::function<Ret (Args...)> Functor_t;
        Functor_t get(Fn_t pFn)
        {
            return [pFn](Args... as){
                return pFn(as...);
            };
        }
    };

    auto fn1 = CdeclCall<int,int>().get( ccall );
    auto fn2 = StdCall<int,int>().get( stdcall );

    fn1(123);
    fn2(156);
```

Comment: Note that this calling convention stuff is nonstandard

Comment: On a 64 bit machine there is only `__fastcall`. This is the reason why it works with a 64 bit compile. `__stdcall` and `__cdecl` are simply ignored by the x64 compiler.

Comment: Does it help if you use `std::function<int __stdcall (int)> fnstd = stdcall;` and `std::function<int __fastcall (int)>`?

Comment: tanks for you answer. but the compiler doesn´t like this syntax:
error: variable 'std::function<int(int)> fnstd' has initializer but incomplete type

i ended up doing it this way:
  template<class Ret, class... Args> class StdCall
  {
  public:
   typedef Ret(__stdcall Fn_t)(Args...);
   typedef std::function<Ret (Args...)> Functor_t;
   Functor_t get(Fn_t pFn)
   {
    return [pFn](Args... as){
     return pFn(as...);
    };
   }
  };

  auto fn1 = CdeclCall<int,int>().get( ccall );
  auto fn2 = StdCall<int,int>().get( stdcall );

  fn1(123);
  fn2(156);

Comment: sry for that mess of comment. i edited my initial post with my "solution"

Comment: reply to your own post, there is nothing wrong with that...

Answer (score 0):

Count yourself lucky. Think about the kind of havoc a function call with the wrong calling convention could cause! Oh, and just create a shim function with the "right" calling convention that calls the "wrong" one. Perhaps you can hide this in a separately compiled file.